# For loop basic ouput

Tags: c++

This is a very basic problem and I am probably confusing myself over with it , but if I have a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
cout << " " << i;
```

Now, lets assume the value of n = 3.

i = 0, i < 3, i = 0 + 1 = 1

i = 1, i < 3, i = 1 + 1 = 2

i = 2, i < 3, i = 2 + 1 = 3

i = 3, i < 3 (False)

So the program terminates and outputs 0 , 1 , 2 , 3. ( I know this is wrong, but shouldn't it display all those values because when i = 2, it satisfies the condition and now the value of i = 3 so the program should output 3 as well ?

Sorry, if this is a stupid question.

Comment: The condition is checked before the body of the loop runs, and the `i++` runs after the body of the loop.

Comment: *Sorry, if this is a stupid question.* It is not a stupid question. However, your understanding of the `for` loop works is not correct. Perhaps understanding the basics of the language from [a good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will help.

Comment: @iz_ Oh All right ! Thanks a lot. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `for (A; B; C) D;` is roughly equivalent to:

```
 {
     A;
     while (B)
     {
         D;
         C;
     }
}
```

Notice that the condition is checked before the statement in the loop is executed. Notice that the condition is checked immediately after the statement is executed and there's another check of the condition before the statement gets to run again.

So your example never outputs `i = 3` because when `i` is 3, the condition is false and the condition is *always* checked before the loop statement executes.

My personal recommendation is to avoid getting clever with the `if` statement. Understand what conditions like `i != 0`, `i < n`, `i <= n` and a few others do and, pretty much, only use the `if` statement in those simple cases. Otherwise, there's too great a risk that someone will read the code incorrectly.

Comment: So, for a do while loop the program will output 0, 1 , 2 , 3 because the condition is checked at the end of the loop ?